# Need help with this DS+ proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am using SD+ I am new to it

I thought of using Negation but if l can construct  3 I should get K

Derive K

1. $(W \supset S)\&\lnot M \qquad$  Assume
2. $(-W \supset H )\lor M \quad$ Assume
3. $(~S\supset H)\supset K\qquad$ Assume
4. $W \supset S \qquad\qquad\quad$  1 & E
5. $\lnot S\supset \lnot W \qquad\qquad$ 4 Trans
6. $|\quad \lnot S\qquad\qquad\qquad$ Assume
7. $|\quad \lnot M\qquad\qquad$ 1&E
8. $|\quad \lnot W\supset H\qquad$   7 DS
9. $|\quad W \lor H\qquad\quad$ 8 Impl
10. $|\quad|\quad \lnot W\qquad\quad$ Assume?
11. $|\quad|\quad H\qquad\qquad$ 9,10 DS
12. $|\quad|\quad \lnot S\lor H\quad$ 4,11 Impl
13. $|\quad|\quad \lnot S\supset H\qquad$  9. impl
14. $|\quad|\quad (\lnot S\supset H)\supset K.\quad$   13 Impl
15. $|\quad|\quad K.\qquad\qquad$ 4-15 Impl.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We do not know your SD+... We can use standard ND rules.

Comment: We want $K$? We have to derive $(\lnot S \to H)$

Comment: How to do it? Assume $\lnot S$ and "search for" $H$

Comment: The point is to use SD+. I believe l mentioned to use ~S$\supset$ H to get K . I did state line 3

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From what I've found, SD uses standard ND rules, except that its $\lnot$ elimination rule is RAA.   SD+ extends this with derived rules (such as modus tollens, disjunctive syllogism, hypothetical syllogism, et cetera).

Comment: Like the way you formatted my proof @Graham Kemp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

You have most of the work you needed done to line 8.   On line 9, you do not need to assume $\lnot W$, you *derive* it using implication elimination.   Then the path to deriving $K$ is clear.

$$\fitch{~~1.~~(W \supset S)\&\lnot M\\~~2.~~(\lnot W \supset H )\lor M\\~~3.~~(\lnot S\supset H)\supset K}{~~4.~~W\supset S\hspace{9ex}\&\mathsf E~1\\~~5.~~\lnot S\supset\lnot W\hspace{6ex}\textsf{Trans}~4\text{ (Contraposition)}\\\fitch{~~6.~~\lnot S}{~~7.~~\lnot M\hspace{9ex}\&\mathsf E~1\\~~8.~~\lnot W\supset H\hspace{4ex}\textsf{DS}~2,7\hspace{3ex}{\color{green}\checkmark}\\[1ex]\color{red}{~~9.~~\lnot W\hspace{9ex}{\supset}\mathsf{E}~5,6}\\\color{red}{10.~~H\hspace{11ex}{\supset}\mathsf E~8.9}}\\\color{red}{11.~~\lnot S\supset H\hspace{8ex}{\supset}\mathsf I~7{-}10}\\\color{red}{12.~~K\hspace{14ex}{\supset}\mathsf E~3,11}}$$

---

Note: Much effort could be saved if you may use Hypothetical Syllogism.  $$\lnot S\supset \lnot W, \lnot W\supset H\vdash \lnot S\supset H$$

Comment: Actually l used HS